# collect security-related events from docusign REST API?

Tags: api, docusignapi

I am going through some of the code examples provided by docusign and going through the API reference docs (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference) trying to get a grasp of how to work with the REST API. My question is: if I wanted to collect logs or events that are security-information-related such as bad logins or anything that might be relevant to a SIEM solution, where might I find them? specifically, what endpoints might I want to pull from? This collecting would be in the context of using a third party (non-web) app to authenticate using the JWT method and collect this information with API calls.

Comment: We do have the Monitor product, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anon,
thanks for your question.
At this time (March 2020) the capabilities you're looking for do not exist in any of the DocuSign APIs.
There are many things you can do with our APIs, but security-related events are not yet something you can get from them. 
Sorry I don't have better news.

Inbar

Answer (score 2):

DocuSign has just announced DocuSign Monitor. [DocuSign Monitor Administration and API Guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/Protect-your-DocuSign-eSignature-deployment-with-DocuSign-Monitor). It is designed to assist with your SIEM product. It directly supports Splunk and has an API for integration with other systems.

Comment: is it possible to gather event data from it via REST calls?

Comment: Re API: See page 17 of the doc. Link is in my answer.